# Cannot find setup.exe in office offline rar data file

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office

I downloaded a rar file couple months ago that includes (***Microsoft.Office.LTSC.2021.Pro.Plus.v2303.Build.16227.20280.x64***) data files in .cab and .cat files([An image of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrtM8.png)) but It has no **setup.exe** so..
I installed it back then using a **command in cmd**; but i forgot what was it.

I've been searching for a while now but didn't find any answer.. all im finding is office deployment tool - I didn't need it though - so can anyone tell me a **cmd command** that can help me?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.